# Simulate C++ template in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

I am trying to figure out the best way to create an alternative to the C++ template or the Java generic objects.  I have wanted to do this several times in the past for several different reasons, however right now what I want to do is related to creating the saveobj and loadobj functions for several related classes.  The idea is that I want to have a generic set of routines to create a default struct and then manipulate that a little bit farther to get the structs the way I want them.

I cannot simply use an external function because I need access to all the public (not a problem) and protected (problem) non-transient properties of an object in order to create the loadobj and saveobj.

Then I considered using an abstract interface.  However, using an abstract interface leaves me with the same problem; identical, copy an pasted code floating around in all of my object files.  So then I thought of using some sort of full blown object combined with multiple inheritance (Most of my objects are already inheriting from a basic concretion of interfaces).  I thought using a superclass would allow me to expose the subclass protected properties, but it doesn't seem to work that way.  Any suggestions?

Here is a sample of the multiple inheritance approach (the closest thing I have so far) for the save obj approach.

Serializer.m

```
% Serializer.m
classdef Serializer 

  methods
    function [saveObj] = saveobj( obj )

      % Get metadata about the Object
      meta = metaclass( obj );
      meta = meta.PropertyList;

      for p = meta'
        if p.Transient | p.Dependent
          continue; % Only serialize the correct fields
        end

        saveobj.(p.Name) = { obj.(p.Name) }; % Serialize
      end % for ( property )
    end % function ( saveobj )
  end % methods
end % classdef ( Serializer )
```

TestSerializerA.m

```
% TestSerializerA.m
classdef TestSerializerA < Serializer
  properties
    PropA = 'a';
  end % properties ( public )

  properties( Access = protected )
    HiddenA = 'ha'
  end % properties ( protected )
end % classdef ( TestSerializerA )
```

TestSerializerB.m

```
% TestSerializerB.m
classdef TestSerializerB < TestSerializerA & Serializer

  properties
    PropB = 'b'
  end

  properties( Access = protected )
    HiddenB = 'hb';
  end % properties ( protected )

end % classdef ( TestSerializerB )
```

Comment: I do not think it is possible to override saveobj and do it across the entire hierarchy having non-public properties. Each class will need to package itself.

Comment: If you mean because `saveobj` and `loadobj` are is a standard built in functions, I thought of that.  In my development code, I called it Serialize and Deserialize and called them from the load and save functions just in case.  Do you think that there would be a way to do it using non-builtin functions?

Comment: No. You will not be able to access protected and private properties.

Comment: Can you recommend any alternatives to the multiple inheritance superclass method?

Comment: If each object packages itself, the leaf should call parent methods and package it. So if you have serialize in every level, you would call superdata = serialize@<mysuperclass>(obj); and then each class would have this same pattern.

Comment: MATLAB is probably the worst language you could choose to use to build a class hierarchy, much less use it for *generics*.

Comment: I mostly agree with Phillip. This approach will end in tears. Can you tell us a little bit more about why you're doing this, and what the intended end result is? Maybe there's a better Matlab mechanism that could accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You can accomplish what you are looking to do by using [Access lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/selective-access-to-class-methods.html#bs_tdu7). You can allow the `Serializer` class access to any protected/private class members you would like to be serialized. This allows each class to determine on its own which of its members are serialized. Since you are allowing access to `Serializer`, you do not want to inherit from it. If you do, all classes in the heirarchy will have access to those members. Here is the rewritten `Serializer` class:

```
classdef Serializer

    methods
        function SerializedObj = serialize(~, Obj)
            % Get metadata about the Object
            meta = metaclass(Obj);
            meta = meta.PropertyList;

            for p = meta' %'
                if p.Transient || p.Dependent
                    continue; % Only serialize the correct fields
                end
                try
                    SerializedObj.(p.Name) = { Obj.(p.Name) }; % Serialize
                catch Me
                    % the class has chosen not to allow this property to be
                    % serialized. decide how to handle it.
                    if ~strcmp(Me.identifier, 'MATLAB:class:GetProhibited')
                        Me.rethrow()
                    end
                end
            end
        end 

    end 

end
```

Note that you can decide how you want to handle the access restrictions. In the above example, I do nothing. But you could issue a warning, throw an error, etc... .

Now, instead of inheriting from `Serializer`, create an abstract `Serializable` class, which will enable serialization.

```
classdef (Abstract) Serializable

    properties (Access = private)
        Serializer_ = Serializer()
    end

    methods        
        function savedObj = saveobj(This)
            savedObj = This.Serializer_.serialize(This);
        end 

    end

end
```

Now any class you wish to enable serialization on will additionally inherit from `Serializable`. You can specify which protected/private members the `Serializer` has access to.

### Examples

The following class has two serializable properties, and one hidden (not serializable) property.

```
classdef TestSerializerA < Serializable
  properties
    PropA = 'a';
  end

  properties( Access = {?TestSerializerA, ?Serializer} )
      % This property is protected and serializable
      SerializableA = 'sa'
  end 

  properties (Access = private)
      % This property is private and not serializable
      HiddenA = 'ha';
  end
end
```

This is the result from MATLAB:

```
>> Test = TestSerializerA

Test = 

  TestSerializerA with properties:

    PropA: 'a'

>> b = saveobj(Test)

b = 

            PropA: {'a'}
    SerializableA: {'sa'}
```

The next example inherits from `TestSerializerA`, and has an additional two serializable properties, and one hidden property.

```
classdef TestSerializerB < TestSerializerA & Serializable

    properties
        PropB = 'b';
    end

    properties (Access = {?TestSerializerB, ?Serializer})
        % This property is protected and serializable.
        SerializableB = 'sb';
    end

    properties (Access = protected)
        % This property is protected and not serializable.
        HiddenPropB = 'hb';
    end

end
```

Note here that re-inheriting from `Serializable` is unnecessary, but makes for easier to read code.

Lastly, the result from MATLAB:

```
>> Test = TestSerializerB

Test = 

  TestSerializerB with properties:

    PropB: 'b'
    PropA: 'a'

>> b = saveobj(Test)

b = 

            PropB: {'b'}
    SerializableB: {'sb'}
            PropA: {'a'}
    SerializableA: {'sa'}
```

I hope this helps!